# Request access for Contacts (Calendar, Reminders, Facebook etc) customized message

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

How can I set my own customized message when asking the user to grant access for Contacts (Reminders, Facebook etc)?

As you can see from below picture is the Path app asking for access to Contacts:

[image]

Comment: Ok, that is weird. Because I've never seen the message "Not all apps recover..." when I ask for access for Contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [iOS 6 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html):

> In iOS 6, there are improved privacy controls for Calendar, Reminders, Contacts, and Photos.
>   Users will see access dialogs when an app tries to access any of those data types. The user can switch access on and off in Settings > Privacy.
>   Developers can set a “purpose” string for each class of isolated data. iOS displays this string to users to help them understand why their data is being requested. These strings can be added using Xcode’s Project editor, which is in the Info tab. The relevant key names begin with the string “Privacy -”.

[image: Editing Privacy Settings in Xcode]

Comment: Ah great thanks! Seems to be missing for Twitter and Facebook though. Do you know if you can localize this text?

Comment: Yes, you can localize Info.plist files -- see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html